# How to remove "Select Visible", "Unselect Visible" and Next Page buttons from grid

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-grid

I have a custom grid, and I wanna remove the highlighted parts from it: [image]

I wanna remove only from my custom grid. What would be the best way?

This is my Grid.php:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setFilterVisibility(false);
    $this->setId('integrationGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->unsetChild('reset_filter_button');
    $this->unsetChild('search_button');
}


protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/integration')->getCollection();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}


protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn(
        'integrate_option',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->__('Integrate'),
            'index'     => 'integrate_option',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'filter'    => false,
            'renderer'  => 'Novapc_Allnations_Block_Adminhtml_Integration_Renderer_Syncproducts',
            'sortable'  => false
        )
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'updated_at',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->__('Updated at'),
            'index'     => 'updated_at',
            'width'     => '300px',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'filter'    => false,
            'renderer'  => 'Novapc_Allnations_Block_Adminhtml_Integration_Renderer_Updatedat',
            'sortable'  => false
        )
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'first_update',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->__('First update'),
            'index'     => 'first_update',
            'width'     => '300px',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'filter'    => false,
            'renderer'  => 'Novapc_Allnations_Block_Adminhtml_Integration_Renderer_Createdat',
            'sortable'  => false
        )
    );
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}


/**
 * get the grid url
 *
 * @access public
 * @return string
 * @author .
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}


protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $this->getCollection()->walk('afterLoad');
    parent::_afterLoadCollection();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('allnations_integration');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
        'integratecat',
        array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->__('Integrar Categorias'),
            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/massCategory')
        )
    )
        ->addItem(
            'integrateprod',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->__('Integrar Produtos'),
                'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/massIntegrateProduct')
            )
        )
        ->addItem(
            'updatestock',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->__('Atualizar Estoque'),
                'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/massUpdateStock')
            )
        )->setUseSelectAll(false);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Pager use this code at grid.php:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setPagerVisibility(false);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

For remove checkboxes, use below code at grid.php (same file):

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
     return $this;
}
```

To only remove checkboxes.

At grid.php

add this line above _construct() function

```
protected $_massactionBlockName = 'Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Massaction';
```

Aftert that create file at Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Massaction.php

Massaction.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Massaction extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('module/widget/grid/massaction.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve select all functionality flag check
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getUseSelectSection()
    {
        return $this->_getData('use_select_all_section') === null || $this->_getData('use_select_all_section');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve select all functionality flag check
     *
     * @param boolean $flag
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction_Abstract
     */
    public function setUseSelectSection()
    {
        $this->setData('use_select_all_section', (bool) $flag);
        return $this;       
    }
}
```

And at end massaction.phtml

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
?>
<div id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="massaction">
<tr>
    <?php $this->getUseSelectSection(): ?>
        <td><?php if ($this->getUseSelectAll()):?>
            <a href="#" onclick="return <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.selectAll()"><?php echo $this->__('Select All') ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <a href="#" onclick="return <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.unselectAll()"><?php echo $this->__('Unselect All') ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a href="#" onclick="return <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.selectVisible()"><?php echo $this->__('Select Visible') ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <a href="#" onclick="return <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.unselectVisible()"><?php echo $this->__('Unselect Visible') ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <strong id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-count">0</strong> <?php echo $this->__('items selected') ?>
        </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="entry-edit">
                <?php if ($this->getHideFormElement() !== true):?>
                <form action="" id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-form" method="post">
                <?php endif ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                    <fieldset>
                        <span class="field-row">
                            <label><?php echo $this->__('Actions') ?></label>
                            <select id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-select" class="required-entry select absolute-advice local-validation">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"<?php echo ($_item->getSelected() ? ' selected="selected"' : '')?>><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="outer-span" id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-form-hiddens"></span>
                        <span class="outer-span" id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-form-additional"></span>
                        <span class="field-row">
                            <?php echo $this->getApplyButtonHtml() ?>
                        </span>
                    </fieldset>
                <?php if ($this->getHideFormElement() !== true):?>
                </form>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>

            <div class="no-display">
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <div id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-item-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>-block">
                    <?php echo $_item->getAdditionalActionBlockHtml() ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php if(!$this->getParentBlock()->canDisplayContainer()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.setGridIds('<?php echo $this->getGridIdsJson() ?>');
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

You are done!!!..

Comment: Thank you! The pager visibility part worked fine. But I don't wanna remove my checkboxes, just the "select visible" and "unselect visible" part. Do you think thats possible?

Comment: Please check my updated asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid.phtml`

`line no 59 to 96`

```
<td class="pager" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo $this->__('Page') ?>

            <?php $_curPage  = $this->getCollection()->getCurPage() ?>
            <?php $_lastPage = $this->getCollection()->getLastPageNumber() ?>
            <?php if($_curPage>1): ?>
                <a href="#" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Previous page')) ?>" onclick="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.setPage('<?php echo ($_curPage-1) ?>');return false;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Go to Previous page')) ?>" class="arrow"/></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left_off.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Go to Previous page')) ?>" class="arrow"/>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getVarNamePage() ?>" value="<?php echo $_curPage ?>" class="input-text page" onkeypress="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.inputPage(event, '<?php echo $_lastPage ?>')"/>

            <?php if($_curPage < $_lastPage): ?>
                <a href="#" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Next page')) ?>" onclick="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.setPage('<?php echo ($_curPage+1) ?>');return false;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Go to Next page')) ?>" class="arrow"/></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right_off.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Go to Next page')) ?>" class="arrow"/>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->__('of %s pages', $this->getCollection()->getLastPageNumber()) ?>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <?php echo $this->__('View') ?>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
                <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
                <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
                <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
                <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
                <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
            </select>
            <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?><span class="separator">|</span>
            <?php echo $this->__('Total %d records found', $this->getCollection()->getSize()) ?>
            <span id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>-total-count" class="no-display"><?php echo $this->getCollection()->getSize() ?></span>
            <?php if($this->getRssLists()): ?>
                <?php foreach ($this->getRssLists() as $_rss): ?>
                <span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $_rss->getUrl() ?>" class="link-feed"><?php echo $_rss->getLabel() ?></a>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
```

And
Go to `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid\massaction.phtml`

`line no 36 to 40`

```
<a href="#" onclick="return <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.selectVisible()"><?php echo $this->__('Select Visible') ?></a>
        <span class="separator">|</span>
        <a href="#" onclick="return <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.unselectVisible()"><?php echo $this->__('Unselect Visible') ?></a>
        <span class="separator">|</span>
```

Remove those code.

showing like this
[image]

Comment: you want to remove  only `Select Visible & Unselect Visible` right ?

Comment: I wanna remove all highlighted parts of the screenshot. Also, wouldn't that remove it from all my grids?

Comment: Now see my answer

Comment: Didn't work properly. It removed both, but it printed the code that called it in the screen. Also, it removed from ALL grids, and I wanna remove just from my custom one. But thanks

Comment: see my screen-short for me it's working, can you pls show your output

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/GKtMM8n.png here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65646/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-stordon).

Comment: @RameshS No need to change any core files for the remove pagination and select visible etc

Comment: @Stordon: add your code in question from Grid.php from your custom module.

Comment: @ChiragNandaniya Just updated my question with my Grid.php file

Comment: @ChiragNandaniya: Am not  change any core files. I just hiding those file

Comment: @Stordon: use `style="display:none;"` to hide that section